# Unable to connect Tor browser inside AD client

Tags: security, proxy, tor-install, firewall, proxy-leaks

I'm trying to connect Tor inside the corporate IT network. The workstations are connected through the proxy server and firewall. When the connection failed with 'Connection timeout' error, I tried to access configuration option in Tor and entered proxy address and port number issued by the corporate IT. Basically the IP address for each client machines are providing by the Network Administrator and the workstations are acting as the Active Directory users with firewall.

Comment: If they are using a Socks proxy, I could see there potentially being an issue between Tor Browser's own proxy and your company's proxy. Do you know anyone in IT that you could talk to "off the record" because trying bypass a company's corporate firewall could definitely get you into trouble. Also, I suggest always using a bridge because they will be able to tell if you are using Tor. If you work for the kind of company that deals with money or government contracts, there is a good chance they will block Tor and can tell if you who is trying to use it.

Comment: @JSEvans, please suggest the method to use bridge.

Comment: Here is the bridge website: https://bridges.torproject.org/.  torproject.org is the first place you should go for questions about Tor.